# Problema de encoding Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Boa tarde Pessoal,

Estou trabalhando em um projeto com Spring MVC e Spring Security. Porém o mesmo, está apresentando problema na codificação dos caracteres, quando faço deploy em um servidor externo, ou seja, executo fora do eclipse, alguém já passo por isso e sabe como resolver ? Desde já agradeço. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa Roger,

Você tentou configurar o filtro do `CharacterEncodingFilter` no web.xml do seu projeto:

```xml
<filter>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>  
    <init-param>  
       <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
       <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <init-param>  
       <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>  
       <param-value>true</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
```

Essa configuração é importante justamente pelas diferenças em cada ambiente para o charset. Dá uma olhada também nesse link com todas as configurações de charset para Java (em inglês):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps

Comment: Opa, vou testar aqui. Obrigado.

Comment: E aí, deu certo?

Comment: @dscasto Deu certo sim amigo, muito obrigado pela ajuda.